# Selection of charts in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a simple Shiny app. My goal is to select one of the charts from the drop-down menu and visualization of the selected chart. Below you will see my script.

````
---
title: "Test App"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

# Libraries ----

# App
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Core
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)

# Visualizations
library(ggplot2)

# Data
data=mtcars
data$cyl <- as.factor(data$cyl)

```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
useShinyjs(rmd = TRUE)


selectInput("clusterNum", label = h4("Charts"), 
     choices = list("Chart1" = "Chart1", "Chart2" = "Chart2"), 
     selected = "Chart1")


```


Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart

```{r}


Chart1<-qplot(x = data$wt, y = data$mpg)

Chart2<-qplot(data$cyl, geom = "bar")


num <- reactive(input$clusterNum)

renderPlot(num())

```
````

When I run this script, I can change the names of the Charts (e.g., Chart1 or Chart2) from the drop-down menu, but I can't see a visualization of the selected chart. So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and to have a visualization as in the pic below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `switch` or an `ìf-else` inside your `renderPlot` to display the chosen chart.

Note: `qplot` was depcrecated in `ggplot2 3.4.0` and will probably removed in the future. To take account of this I switched to `ggplot()`.

````
---
title: "Test App"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# Data
data <- mtcars
data$cyl <- as.factor(data$cyl)
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput("clusterNum",
  label = h4("Charts"),
  choices = list("Chart1" = "Chart1", "Chart2" = "Chart2"),
  selected = "Chart1"
)
```


Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart

```{r}
Chart1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()
Chart2 <- ggplot(data, aes(cyl)) +
  geom_bar()

renderPlot({
  switch(input$clusterNum,
    "Chart1" = Chart1,
    "Chart2" = Chart2
  )
})
```
````

[image]